# Possible to have one fixed width cell in Zurb Foundation 5 grid?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Is it possible to set a cell/column in Zurb Foundation to have a minimum  width?
The cell contains a list and some of the items in that list are wrapping and I would like to prevent that. NoWrap keeps them from wrapping but they then overlap the next column's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible in Zurb Foundation 5, only in version 6 with the XY Grid.
However you could use css instead of the grid classes to have the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by 'Foundation Grid' you're referring to their 'XY Grid'... if that's the case one possible solution for you without having to add any additional CSS/SCSS or media queries would be to use the 'shrink' and 'auto' classes on your cells (see code below). Using the 'shrink' class with your cell/column will keep that cell at the width of the longest content (in your case an unordered/ordered list) while auto adjusting to fill the remaining width of the viewport with the remaining cell(s)/column(s) within that grid-x row. If you want the cells/columns to stack on <= medium viewport sizes you simply change the 'medium-[shrink or auto]' to 'large-[shrink or auto]'. For further info, see the Zurb XY Grid 'Auto Sizing' section [here](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/xy-grid.html).

```
<div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="cell medium-shrink">
        <ul>
            <li>No wrapping list item here that has longer content so it will be wider</li>
            <li>No wrapping list item here that has long content</li>
            <li>No wrapping list item here that has long content</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="cell medium-auto">
        Expanded content would be here that fills in the rest of the viewport from >= medium viewport size and then stacks on small viewport size.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes that looks correct for 6.  I neglected to mention that I am using Foundation 5 rather then 6